# Including a standalone component in vue ant design steps

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, antd, ant-design-vue

I want to use any design steps component and i wonder how i can include a standalone component from https://www.antdv.com/components/steps/

```
<template>
  <div>
    <a-steps :current="current">
      <a-step v-for="item in steps" :key="item.title" :title="item.title" />
    </a-steps>
    <div class="steps-content">
      {{ steps[current].content }}
    </div>
    <div class="steps-action">
      <a-button v-if="current < steps.length - 1" type="primary" @click="next">
        Next
      </a-button>
      <a-button
        v-if="current == steps.length - 1"
        type="primary"
        @click="$message.success('Processing complete!')"
      >
        Done
      </a-button>
      <a-button v-if="current > 0" style="margin-left: 8px" @click="prev">
        Previous
      </a-button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      current: 0,
      steps: [
        {
          title: 'First',
          content: 'First-content',
        },
        {
          title: 'Second',
          content: 'Second-content',
        },
        {
          title: 'Last',
          content: 'Last-content',
        },
      ],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    next() {
      this.current++;
    },
    prev() {
      this.current--;
    },
  },
};
</script>
<style scoped>
.steps-content {
  margin-top: 16px;
  border: 1px dashed #e9e9e9;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  min-height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 80px;
}

.steps-action {
  margin-top: 24px;
}
</style>
```

this is the code that assigns content in steps

```
steps: [
        {
          title: 'First',
          content: 'First-content',
        },
        {
          title: 'Second',
          content: 'Second-content',
        },
        {
          title: 'Last',
          content: 'Last-content',
        },
      ],
```

How can i include a standalone `component.vue` here

```
content: 'First-content',
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `content` from a string to a component definition:

```js
import FirstContent from '@/components/FirstContent.vue'
import SecondContent from '@/components/SecondContent.vue'
import LastContent from '@/components/LastContent.vue'

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      steps: [
        {
          title: 'First',
          content: FirstContent,
        },
        {
          title: 'Second',
          content: SecondContent,
        },
        {
          title: 'Last',
          content: LastContent,
        },
      ],
    }
  },
}
```

In your template, replace the string interpolation with `<component>`:

```html
<component :is="steps[current].content" />
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/rendering-dynamic-components-in-vue-t21cy?file=/src/components/Steps.vue)